# VSE Image doesn't show in final render

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm relatively new to VSE, and I'm trying to place an image in my video, but when I render it the image doesn't show at the designated time.

[image]

How can I make blender display the image in my final render?

Comment: There could be quite a few reasons as to why. Can you snapshot your video sequence editor view-ports in full so we know what the scene looks like and what your settings are? We need clarification on what is in the video. The screenshot indicates that you simply f12'd the frame at the time shown. You said you are making a video though, is it just from 0-5s with the image sequence and that's it? For example if you render out a video and stick it back in your timeline and try to line things up, things can be off if you don't assign a timecode under the proxy settings of the strip (use record run)

Comment: Based on the screenshot you showed you are creating a video from 0-4.~ seconds. Your image strip (is it a single still image or a number of them?) will start showing up at 1.5s or so in the video you create. But that's only if the start and end settings are set to what they are in the timeline, it's possible you clicked an option make them different values.

Comment: @kite it's a single image

Comment: @kite I added a new image

Comment: Sorry I'm still not understanding the full picture here. The vse and 3d viewport are two separate entities, and you show both of them in the same image here. The problem could be you are assuming entries in one automatically translate into the other. If you wish to import from the 3d viewport into the vse timeline you must use a scene strip, or render out and re-insert as an image/video strip. If you wish to have things from the vse showup in the 3d viewport....you'll have to render out from the vse and re-insert as an image strip directly into the 3d viewport via nodes or applying to a mesh

Comment: If that isn't the case please do a few test renders using just the vse to confirm any problems (render out a series of colour strips for example in the vse: shift+a->effect strip->colour (while cursor in the timeline)). Then please check things like framerate of the video created and make sure it matches with the assigned fps, 24 fps u have here. I'm not familiar with avi jpeg. I would say try using ffmpeg avi h.264 just to confirm that you 'can' render out of the vse properly. Isolate the problem based on that. If you toss ur video back in, assign a timecode to confirm things lineuep